# Contextual or global: action label in Navigation Bar and Segmented Control

Tags: ios, controls, contextual-menu, segmented

I'm trying to layout a screen where users could delete some content using the classic iOS pattern:

1. tap on the Nav-Bar's "edit" label (top-right)
2. then tick the items to delete
3. validate

Nothing complicated here, right?

But what if I need to add a **segmented control**?

[image]

**Is the edit label supposed to be *"global"* to this screen**, whichever segmented control we're on?

**Or could this edit label be *contextual*** and disappear or change if we press on *"section2"/"section3"*.

In my case, I just need the deletion feature on *"section1"*. I might either not need a top-left label on the other remaining sections or need a different one.
I'm asking because, **due to its location, the *"edit"* label appears to be related to the page and not the the active segment below**.
Would it go against iOS guidelines to make this label *contextual* and therefore change according to the active segmented control?
Have you ever encountered such case?

Best regards,
M-Design

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be totally fine with the Edit button contextually relevant to the content or segment. You can try to disable or hide the Edit button when users switch to other segments.

But it's true that the location of the button makes it a bit like for the whole page. The alternative approach would be that having the Edit button in the header of the table view, instead of in the navigation header.

Another thing to consider is that to use the cell-swipe gesture (swiping on a row all the way to the left or right to trigger actions).

Comment: Thank you Stephenye! The cell-swipe gesture would be a good UX-pattern for this case indeed!
However, I still need to consider the _"batch-deletion"_ feature with the edit label somewhere.

Comment: No problem. True, batch-deletion is still needed even if you have cell-swipe. Let us know which approach you settle on, as it's a valid use case :)

Answer (score 1):

The existing approach you have taken is perfectly fine and doesn't go against iOS guidelines. Try and see if you can place the edit action in footer of the page.

Even iOS follows the same convention - check their **Clock** app and see the Alarm & World Clock tabs.

**Edit:**

If you see, the **Edit** option is same for the **World Clock and Alarm Tab**

[image]

Comment: Hi Dipak! Thanks for the feed-back! I don't see the segmented control on the iOS Clock app, so there isn't confusion apparently there, am I right? As for the footer, I'm afraid users would need to scroll too much to be able to get this action done.

Comment: @M-Design Check the edited post. And keep the footer fixed to bottom so that the user doesn't have to scroll much.

Comment: Hi @Dipak! Thanks for the feed-back! Actually, the app has the iOS tab-bar component implemented already [as the updated image shows here](http://imgur.com/AwOQ5Q1). So in my case, the screen relates to the last tab-bar item, so the scroll can still be long here in case there are many elements in the listView.